# How to exclude layout?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

My ASP.NET Core web project has the usual shared layout file.

How do I exclude the use of layout for a specific page?

Comment: Have you tried setting Layout = null; in razor view ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
@{
  Layout = null;
}
```

Stick that at the top of your view to not use any layout. Bear in mind you'll need to specify a full HTML document body in that view.